# How to Write code to do programmatically rest factory works on Lineage OS without problems?

Tags: rest, factory, lineageos

How to programmatically restore factory restore settings without problems I tried it a lot and did not work ?

---

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html#wipe

I tried this on Android OS and working successfully but in Lineage OS didn't work :(